# how to de-normalize values normalized by linalg.norm method of numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, normalize

I have an array

```
a = array([[ 3.55679502,  3.46622505],
           [ 1.03670334,  2.43254031],
           [ 1.12185975,  3.25257322]])
```

Now I normalized it with numpys `linalg.norm` method

```
norm_a = a/np.linalg.norm(a)
```

It gives normalized values in  the range of (0,1) as

```
norm_a = array([[ 0.53930891,  0.52557599],
                [ 0.15719302,  0.36884067],
                [ 0.1701051 ,  0.49318044]])
```

Now, using `norm_a`, how can I recover original de-normalized matrix `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the opposite, simple maths really:

```
In [310]:    
norm_a * np.linalg.norm(a)

Out[310]:
array([[ 3.55679502,  3.46622505],
       [ 1.03670334,  2.43254031],
       [ 1.12185975,  3.25257322]])
```

Comment: Isn't `a` unknown because that's what we are trying to get back?

Comment: @Divakar I was assuming that since the OP had normalised `a` they still had `a`

Comment: @Divakar saying that I see your point, will have a think and update

Comment: I guess we are assuming that OP had stored that scalar `np.linalg.norm(a)` beforehand.

Comment: In any case the "denormalized" array might be slightly different - because no(t every) floating point operation is bijective so there might be slight errors.

Comment: @MSeifert that's true

Answer (score 1):

You are basically scaling down the entire array by a scalar. The scaling factor has to be used for retrieving back. That scaling factor would be  `np.linalg.norm(a)` and could be stored while computing the normalized values and then used for retrieving back `a` as shown in [`@EdChum's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43675951/3293881). Another way would would be to store one of the elements off the original array `a`, say the first element and then use it with division against the corresponding element in the normalized array and get that scaling factor.

Thus, the other way would be -

```
a = norm_a*(a[0,0]/norm_a[0,0])
```

Again, if the chosen element is too small or big compared to the corresponding element in the normalized array, we might have slight differences. So, I am guessing using `np.linalg.norm(a)` would be the safest way here.